# Not Able to display array json values on html by ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

For autocomplete texbox I am using `ngTagInput`.  And suggestions are coming as well.

When I am trying to display `data-ng-model` (suppose name is "list") values I am doing like: `{{list}}` and then it's displaying correctly.

If I am selecting "list1" then it is displaying like:

```
[{"listId":1,"listName":"list1"}]
```

But when I am trying to display only listId like: `{{list.listId}}`, it's not displaying anything not even `{{list.listName}}`

Please help me out

Thank you.

Here is my html:

```
<tags-input ng-model="list" display-property="listName" on-tag-added="getlists()" >
     <auto-complete source="loadlists($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<p>Id is: {{list.listId}}</p><br>
<p>Name is {{list.listName}}</p>

</tags-input>
```

Here is my js:-

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('resources/json/tags.json');
};

$scope.getlists = function(){
    //not implemented
};
```

Here `{{list}}` is  :-

```
[{"listId":2,"listName":"Tag2"}]
```

My json is:-

```
[
    { "listId": 1, "listName": "list1" },
    { "listId": 2, "listName": "list2" },
    { "listId": 3, "listName": "list3" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON is an array you need to access it as:

`list[0].listId` and `list[0].listName`

See the plunkr: "http://plnkr.co/edit/yRwvyfXUwNibCuNOHuZU?p=preview"

Comment: But user can select any list from the autocomplete tag.I mean if suppose user want to add 10 lists as tags then it will only bind zero index value to model..

Comment: As per your question I just gave you the approach on what mistake you were making, at the end of the day you will have to decide the logic and that need to be an entirely new question.